# Lubuntu login loop after changing i3 config

Tags: lubuntu, login

So I recently changed a bunch of i3 configs like customs shortcuts and more importantly the workspaces name and now sddm is not allowing me to login when I enter my password the screen goes black and I am back on the login screen . I tried to go into terminal using ctrl alt f2 but when I enter my details the screen clears and I am on the login screen again
Edit : I also cant login in any of other desktop environments

Comment: Do you have space in $HOME (your user directory), as GUI logins cannot create necessary *work files* if space is too low... You've not said which release, but a text login will still work.

Comment: Use Ctrl alt F3 or higher to go into terminal.

Comment: What happens when you revert the changes you made?  What changes did you make?

Comment: I cant login in any terminal I pressed ctrl alt f3 and then terminal comes I login it says welcome to ubuntu or something like that and then i go back to the tty login screen again

Comment: I cant revert changes cuz it's not allowing me to get into any desktop or any terminal

Comment: I don't know what release; but it sounds like whatever change you made is the problem & it is causing the logout to occur... I'd boot *live* media & explore your changes from there, where I'd assume it'll be quickly found & corrected, but given we don't know what change(s) you made it'll be far harder for us to guess (we still don't know your release) and we don't have your recollections of what & where you made changes which is where i'd look.  (I'd expect you could login by stopping boot at runlevel 1, but as I don't know your OS & release details I have insufficient detail of your stack)

Comment: That's the exact problem I cant find the live usb 